# Excel Filling a list by matching headers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables: A giant list of people in the rows with groups in the columns.  X's denote which person in a row belongs to each group.
In my other table I have group names lining the columns.  I'm looking for a formula that will lookup and match the group name(headers) and then return the name in column A for each X.  I have tried some array functions to no avail

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that in the first table (TABLE A; A1:D5), you have group names in cells B1:D1.
In the second table (TABLE B; F1:G5), group names are in cells F1:H1, and may be in a different order. In the TABLE B, you need to look up the relative position of a group name, as it appears in TABLE A. We use the [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) function for this. We then get the value of a cell from TABLE A that is in the same row, but from a column that is *offset* from B by the relative position. We use the [`OFFSET`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) function for this. Putting it all together, we have:

```
IF(OFFSET($B2,0,MATCH(F$1,$B$1:$D$1,0)-1)="X",$A2,"")
```

[image: Worksheet screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! This works great, but if I have a large list of names, is there a way to track through with a formula like "small" to not fill in blanks?

Comment: I was able to figure it out by adding an array.  
        =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$999,SMALL(IF(OFFSET($B2,0,MATCH(F$1,$B$1:$D$1,0)-1)="X",ROW(F$1:F$99)),ROW(F1))),""))  [then CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER]